# Упаковка прямоугольников с возможностью поворота?

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

Как называется алгоритм упаковки прямоугольников, 
где главное
 - максимальная компактность
 - прямоугольники можно поворачивать
 - можно сдвигать с места, уже упакованный, чтобы получше упаковать.

Если есть реализация на PHP! то можно и ссылку на реализацию.

Comment: Поворачивать только на 90 градусов, или на любой угол? Компактность - это площадь bounding box'а? Или его максимальная сторона? Или площадь фигуры, ограниченной внешней оболочкой? Или площадь выпуклой оболочки?

Comment: 90. Ну компактность, чтобы как можно больше прямоугольников влезло в заданные ширина-высота.

Comment: Как можно больше и в заданные? А размеры одинаковые?

Comment: Статья с хабра: https://habrahabr.ru/post/136225/

Comment: Разные размеры у каждого. Задаваться должны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос - алгоритм носит название [Задача об упаковке в контейнеры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) ([Bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)).